# Tool tip vanishes after drag and drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, tooltip

I have got a C# UserControl in a Windows Forms Application which supports drag and drop. In my case, the location of the Control is not changed when dragging, only a new Control is spawned where the cursor is released.
This UserControl also owns a ToolTip. When I move my mouse over the Control, the tool tip pops up. Drag and drop also works fine.

But after doing drag and drop from the Control, the tool tip doesn't pop up any more.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem without re-creating the tooltip after any drag and drop operation?

Answer (score 0):

Just write `tooltip.isopen=true;`